# Где можно подробней узнать о регулярных выражениях?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, pandas

В датафреймах нужно фильтровать **при учете разных условий** ,чтобы ,допустим, в столбце в любом порядке встречались разные символы.

Когда я ,например ,прописываю

```
df.d.str.extract(r'((?i)а.*)(?i)в.*20)', expand=False)
```

чтобы найти строки с буквой "а" и "в" ,с последующей "20", **только с учетом того, что 20 следует после "в"**, не учитывая порядок первого и второго условий.

1. Где необходимо указывать условия "и", "или", "не содержит"?, в случае необходимости?
2. Почему с моим фильтром результат разделяется на два столбца?
3. Где я могу больше узнать о регулярных выражениях?

Comment: было бы проще если бы вы привели в вопросе несколько примеров строк и то что вы хотите из них получить...

Comment: Вы не могли бы конкретизировать, что вам надо?

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте онлайн на https://regex101.com/

```
((?i)а.*)(?i)в.*20) <-- на последнюю скобку ругается
```

если без неё то находит:

текст1 **а в 20**

текст2 **а вчера мне было 20** лет

Comment: *Почему с моим фильтром результат разделяется на два столбца?* - В коде ТС опечатка, на самом деле, там столько скобок, сколько надо.